# How to watch a specific file in saltstack and perform any operation when anything changes in the file?

Tags: watch, salt-stack

I am using a Raspberry Pi for this setup. Background is I have a button attached on Pi which toggles GPIO Pin value. Whenver this button is pressed the Pi should revert to a specific IP. I am setting up a salt-state (master-less minion) in Pi which would look at a file in /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value. The value in this file is either "0" or "1" depending upon the voltage provided to this GPIO pin. My end result should be to execute a bash script or replace an interfaces file so that Pi could be accessible on that specific IP.

I have already made a file exactly like /etc/network/interfaces and put it in my salt directory. I used file.managed to replace the file and it worked, however I need this state to run when I press the button. I have already tried watch in salt-stack but I was not successful in it. Can anyone give me some sample code on how to do this? I am stuck for the past week.

```
watching_service:
    service.running:
        - name: watching
        - enable: True
        - restart: True
        - watch:
            - file: /home/pi/new.conf
    file.managed:
        - source: salt://watch/new.conf
        - name: /home/pi/new.conf
```

- watching_service is a salt-state
- watching is a systemd service which creates an empty folder in /tmp (Not needed)

Currently I am using watch on new.conf and I want it to restart the service whenever I do some change in new.conf.

I have also used onchanges instead of watch but nothing seems to work. I can do this in bash script which would be having an infinite while loop listening to any changes on GPIO Pin but I think that would decrease Pi stability. Correct me if I am wrong. Is there any other way to do this without loop?

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` statement tells a state to run whenever another state has made changes.

Suppose, you had this SLS file in your `file_roots`:

```
cat >/srv/salt/state/example.sls <<_EOF_

manage_the_file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/the_file.txt
    - contents: 'the_content'

run_on_changes:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: echo "I was triggered because manage_the_file was executed"
    - watch:
      - file: manage_the_file

_EOF_
```

Now if you run the command..

```
sudo salt-call state.apply example --state_output changes
```

..you will see the `run_on_changes` state running, but only if the `manage_the_file` state has run as well (due to detected changes). In other words: Salt skips the state `run_on_changes` if `/tmp/the_file.txt` is unchanged, but you still have to call Salt manually.

I think you want to trigger a Salt Highstate upon changes to the file. That is something else.
In Linux [Inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) is the tool to monitor filesystem events.

The "*Salt way*" to use Inotify is to define a [Beacon](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/beacons/all/salt.beacons.inotify.html).
It will trigger an event in Salt, whenever the file changes. Additionally you need a [Reactor](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/) that triggers the Highstate, when the event arrives on the Salt master.

However I think your Usecase doesn't justify a complex configuration like this. Why not use `incrond`?
It's a very convenient way to use Inotify.

```
# Install it
sudo apt-get install incrond  (or the equivalent yum call)

# Make sure at least user root may edit the incrontab
echo "root" |sudo tee -a /etc/incron.allow

# Make sure the watched file exists
sudo mkdir -p /home/pi
sudo touch /home/pi/new.conf

# Add an incrond entry
sudo incrontab -e 
/home/pi/new.conf IN_MODIFY echo "I could have called the restart command for the 'watching' service here!"

# Trigger changes
echo "new content" |sudo tee /home/pi/new.conf
```

You should see the output from the Echo command in your Syslog file (`/var/log/syslog` on Debian).